# Not getting custom category field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

On my App I have created two models **Tutorial** and **Tutorial category** and for tutorial i have created a string field for category ( in migration ) 'tutorialcategory'.

On tutorial add page I have added a selectbox field to select category and it is saving properly ( I hope ) as I can see the value after saving the tutorial in show page. but when I see full list using json render i can not see the value there.

Note : both models are separate and none of these contains reference field in migration

model code as follows

```
class Tutorialcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title

    def to_param
        "#{id}-#{title}"
    end
end



class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :projectcategory, :rating, :title, :tutorialcategory, :videoid
end
```

Comment: for reference : I use = @tutorial.tutorialcategory to show category name

Comment: Why are you still using Rails 3?

Comment: Planning to upgrade, its done 2 years ago.

Comment: Okay bud, I'll write something to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to need a `has_many` relation between `Category` and `Tutorial` :

- Delete the string field named "tutorialcategory" in the tutorials table, create a field named tutorial_category_id (by convention) which will refer to an ID of TutorialCategory.
- In your models, set the has_many/belongs_to association :

  ```
  class Tutorialcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tutorials
  end

  class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tutorial_category
  end
  ```
- Then you can access `tuto.tutorial_category` (tuto is an instance of Tutorial), and `categ.tutorials` (categ is an instance of Category)
- Of course, you'll need to redo your interface to save a tutorial's category by its ID.

Documentation :

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Answer (score 2):

To add to `Caillou`'s answer, there are several other fixes you need.

---

**CamelCase**

Your `Tutorialcategory` model needs to be called `TutorialCategory`:

```
#app/models/tutorial_category.rb
class TutorialCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Whenever Rails loads a model, it expects its name to be [`CamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). It will infer this from the [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) filename; each underscore representing a new capital letter.

-

**View**

In order to populate the `category` through a `has_many` relationship, you'll need to populate the [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) of the associated table:

```
#app/views/tutorials/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @tutorial do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :category_id, TutorialCategory.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will set the `category_id` of the `Tutorial` object in the database -- populating the `tutorial_category` associative method when you call it:

```
#app/models/tutorial.rb
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category, class_name: "TutorialCategory" #-> put category_id in the tutorials table
end

#app/models/tutorial_category.rb
class TutorialCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tutorials #-> no changed needed in db
end
```

[image]

This is how ActiveRecord pulls the associated object from the related table:

```
@tutorial = Tutorial.find x
@tutorial.category.name #-> name of category
```

-

**Alias**

To prevent [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), you may wish to use [`alias_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute) to delegate the `name` to `category`:

```
#app/models/tutorial.rb
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   alias_attribute :name, to: :category, prefix: true #-> @tutorial.category_name
end
```

-

**Strong Params**

Finally, when you upgrade to Rails 4, you'll need to use [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) in your controller. This is a very simple switch:

1. Remove `attr_accessible` from your models
2. Add a "params" method to your controller:

Like this:

```
#app/controllers/tutorials_controller.rb
class TutorialsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @tutorial = Tutorial.new tutorial_params
      @tutorial.save
   end

   private

   def tutorial_params
      params.require(:tutorial).permit(:body, :title, :tutorialcategory)
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, I thought about giving a more complete answer like yours, but I wasn't motivated enough :p